# Trying to add Notification to Google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i'm to trying to add notification to google chrome extension it means that whenever there is a new post on my website the notification will display a small redbox on the extension icon with no 1-10 just like Feedly extension, or unboxtherapy extension in google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Making such a notification appear should be simple:

```
var notification = '#FA2E05'
function showNotification() {
   chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: ' '});
   chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: notification});
}

function clearNotification() {
   chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: ''});
}
```

Here's a helper I tend to use when I'm using badges:

```
function updateBadge(options) {
    var t = options.text,
        c = options.color||options.colour;

    if(t !== undefined){
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: (t||'')});
    }
    if(c !== undefined) {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: c});
    }
}
```

Which lets you update the badge's colour and/or text using
`updateBadge({text:'55'})`//keeping same colour or
`updateBadge({colour:'#FA2E05', text:' '})` //to show the badge (equiv to showBadge())

Comment: where to add this this is my js file
like to the codehttps://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_b7vutPyv8gWDdMM011bThySGs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Somewhere before you want to change badges - personally I keep these functions in a `browser` object which I use as a dependency for my main javascript code. This is useful if in the future I want to port my extensions to other browsers. So I can call `browser.updateBadge({text:33, colour: '#7D4E45'})` if I want to change the badge anywhere in my script assuming my `browser.js` file has loaded.

Comment: please can you help me on this i don't know how to modify it. to bring badges to the notification.

Comment: yes jus like that and the badge shows numbers 1-10. no means(the latest posts)

Comment: Does your extension have an icon (on the extension tray) at the moment?

Comment: The badge will appear as soon as you give it a text length > 1 so calling `updateBadge({text: '33'})` will add a badge with text '33' and the default background to your extensions icon `updateBadge({text:''})` hides the badge

Comment: Sorry i still don't get it. I want to know in what i have to add this code. I'm new to this please
var notification = '#FA2E05'
function showNotification() {
   chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: ' 33'});
   chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: notification});
}

function clearNotification() {
   chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: ''});
}


if i add this code to java script directly would it work for me

Comment: Read chrome's extension documentation I can't help you any more than this

Comment: I don't know how your app is structured so I can't tell you, I have mine in the background page - here's one of my apps https://github.com/megawac/tfstreams but you'll prob have an easier time following the chrome documentation

Comment: if i'll provide you a link to that can you please look at it
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_b7vutPyv8gWDdMM011bThySGs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Don't have permission

Comment: Go with this please
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uyc0et2y11wnv0b/GD%20Feed%20Extension%203.zip

Comment: @user2893320 asking for us to 'fix' arbitrary stuff in your code is out of the scope for this forum

Comment: But essentially you would put the `browser.updateBadge` function somewhere outside of the `initalize` function in `gismodimensions.js` or in its own `browser.js` file and then call `browser.updateBadge({text: String(result.feeds.entries.length)});` or whatever you're planning to set the badge too